# a simple problem about RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text:

```
 <font class="myclass">class abc</font>
```

and i have a pattern: class
now, i want to find the word "class" before "abc" but not in the  `<font class="myclass">` ,how could i do with RegExp in javascript?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Here's why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darin's comment is spot on -- don't use RegEx to parse HTML.

If, however, you have a very narrow requirement to find the word "class" immediately following a `>`, here's your pattern:

`>class`

There is a space at the end. If you need to capture "class" for replacement, surround it with parentheses `( )`, then use the capture group `\1`.

This is not terribly robust, but is a start and is only applicable for a very narrow search requirement, not for any more involved parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Sermons aside, it depends on what you can expect for sure, you can try with:

```
/[^y]class/
/\bclass/
/class abc/
```